# Cannot find _assert() for ascii string in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, assert

As per [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/assert-macro-assert-wassert?view=vs-2019) for `assert` macro, it supports both `_assert()` [for ASCII string] and `_wassert()` [for UNICODE string]. However in the `assert.h` file from Windows Kit folder, it is defined as following:

```
 #define assert(expression) (void)(                                                       \
            (!!(expression)) ||                                                              \
            (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#expression), _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), (unsigned)(__LINE__)), 0) \
        )
```

My project needs the ASCII version of assertion. Is there any other header file where it is defined for `_assert()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no header which defines `assert()` for an `ascii string` i.e. using `_assert()` method. Hence to fit my need I created a local `assert.h` file with the below code and when used it both compiles and links to the proper ascii function.

```
#undef assert

#ifdef NDEBUG

#define assert(expression) ((void)0)

#else

    void __cdecl _assert(
        _In_z_ const* _Message,
        _In_z_ const* _File,
        _In_   unsigned       _Line
        );

#define assert(exp) (void)( (exp) || (_assert(#exp, __FILE__, __LINE__), 0) )

#endif
```

The above is, of course, inspired from the internal `assert.h` header code.

Answer (score 0):

On the MSDN documentation page, it says:

> The signature of the `_assert` function is not available in a header file.

So the answer to your question is: "No". Furthermore, the MSDN page tells you:

> The _assert and _wassert functions are internal CRT functions. They help minimize the code required in your object files to support assertions. We do not recommend that you call these functions directly.

If you want to print an ASCII error message, and die afterwards, I recommend using either MessageBox followed by ExitProcess (for GUI applications) or fputs followed by abort (for console applications).

Comment: The macro `assert` is defined only for the wide char strings. Shouldn't there be an option for the ascii strings? What happens when the project choses to use ascii character-set and still wants to use assert?

Comment: The macro `assert` is not defined for strings. It expects a C expressions, like `assert(i == 3)`. It internally generates a string from the expression, like `"i == 3"` or `L"i == 3"`, but you should not get in touch with that string anyway. Please elaborate in your question, what you really want to achieve.